# NServiceBus, how do you do an action before a message is sent to the error queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I am using NService to create an endpoint.

The endpoint is listening to an event and do some calculation, then publish result (success or fail) to other endpoints

I know that NServiceBus support ImmediateRetry and DelayRetry, and they are configurable.

Now, I want to publish a fail result event to other endpoints after all retries (before sending to error queue).

```
public async Task Handle(MyEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received MyEvent, ID = {message.Id}");

            //Connect to other services to get data and do some calculation
            Thread.Sleep(1000);            


            Console.WriteLine($"Processed MyEvent, ID = { message.Id}");


            await context.Publish(new MyEventResult { IsSucceed = true });
        }
```

Above is my current code. It will publish a successful result if there is no exception throw. But If it has a fatal exception, I don't know how to publish a fail result event before the message is sent to the error queue.

Thanks in advance.

Notes: I am using NServiceBus 6.4.3

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing using version 7.1. I have seen the behaviors but they seem to run after the initial call and each retry....not after all the retries have been exhausted which is what I need to do.

This link says that it will be called after all the retries but it doesnt seem to perform like that:
"This new behavior is registered such that it will be invoked after NServiceBus has invoked the recoverability mechanism. This includes Second-Level Retries if they are enabled."
https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/customizing-error-handling

Comment: @ManOfSteele: thanks for your info. I think the only way is to implement delay retries logic by ourselves :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want this but have you looked at NServiceBus sagas? They are intended to be used when having to doing blocking IO via (external) services. You can take alternative actions based on the fact if a specific task hasn't been performed within an allocated period or because the returned result was incorrect.

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/

See the following sample of a saga:

- https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/simple/

The following is a sample showing the usage of saga timeouts. If specific task has not been performed within a specific duration an alternative action can be performed like publishing an event or performing a `ReplyToOriginator`

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/timeouts
- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/reply-replytooriginator-differences
- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/#notifying-callers-of-status

By using sagas you are making your process explicit. I would avoid hooking into the recovery mechanism for this.

The recovery mechanism is meant to deal with transient errors like network connectivity issues, database deadlocks, etc. but not with expected failure results. You should properly process these and continue your modeled process in its unhappy path.

Comment: I just need to handle transient errors like network issue. But I just want to publish fail event to other services before silently send it to the error queue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is needed?

Comment: I creating an endpoint, which handles an event. In the event handler, it will connect to some web services to get data then do some calculation logic, then upload result back to web services. If everything works fine, I publish a successful event. If not, I want it to retry 2,3 times. If still not work after retries, it will publish fail event.

Comment: Wouldn't saga timeouts work for you? I've added info about saga timeouts. Sagas are often used for such integrations to take alternative actions.